# CSS not applying to injected HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one apply CSS styling to HTML elements inserted by a line of HTML?

A specific example: I'm using [Waitlisted](https://github.com/waitlisted/waitlisted-components) to insert an email form that adds users to a waitlist. The example code in that linked documentation is:

```
<script src="dist/index-with-deps.min.js"></script>

<waitlisted-total domain="waitlisted.app.waitlisted.dev"></waitlisted-total>

<waitlisted-show>
  <waitlisted-error></waitlisted-error>
  <waitlisted-form domain="waitlisted.app.waitlisted.dev"></waitlisted-form>
</waitlisted-show>

<waitlisted-show submitted>
  <waitlisted-reflink>
  Link to share!
  </waitlisted-reflink>
  <waitlisted-refurl></waitlisted-refurl>
  <waitlisted-refurl as="input"></waitlisted-refurl>

  <waitlisted-position></waitlisted-position> of <waitlisted-total></waitlisted-total>
</waitlisted-show>
```

As I understand it, the first line of Javascript injects HTML. But when I try to apply CSS to those HTML elements, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you used the browser inspection tools to check if those elements have line `css`? If those elements have a `style` attribute it will overwrite your current `css` upon rendering but can be modified.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything for CSS rules to apply to injected content. Check your developer's tools (F12) and look at the Elements tab, to see the CSS that is applicable to the elements.

Comment: Thank you both. I look at some of the elements in the inspector. One button, for example, doesn't have a style attribute, so I don't think that's an issue. But even when I put "button { color: red !important;} in my CSS file, it doesn't change the button's appearance, nor does it show up in the inspector.

Comment: You're using an obviously abandoned project. Why?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev It's cheaper and simpler than other options. I've also had this issue with other injected HTML, so I don't think it's just that the project is abandoned. You may have a point though!